# What is the best way to read SQL dataset in to Tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, dataset, sql

What is the best way to read SQL database in to Tensorflow?

Currently, I am using Postgres on server and developed DL algorithm on Tensorflow using Jupyter Lab. How can I import data into Jupyter Lab using `tf.data` API? I do not want to store the data in the disk and keep running the algorithm when the new data arrives.

It seems like `tf.data.experimental.SqlDataset` only support for sqlite.

(NOTE: I did not upgrade my Tensorflow, so, I am using  `tf.contrib.data.SqlDataset()` for the minimal working example.)

I migrated the data from PostgreSQL to SQLite3 and using

```
#Ignore the warnings
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

import tensorflow as tf
#To start an input pipeline, you must define a source
dataset = tf.contrib.data.SqlDataset("sqlite", "/home/musara1/musara_dev.sqlite3",
                                 "SELECT * FROM basetable LIMIT 10",
                                 (tf.string, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32))

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
# Prints the rows of the result set of the above query.
sess=tf.InteractiveSession()

print(sess.run(next_element))
```

I can print the next element. However, there are other transformations I need to do on the dataset. such as splitting into training/validation/testing and getting rid of some columns et cetera. However, the output of `tf.contrib.data.SqlDataset()` is for me
`<SqlDataset shapes: ((), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ()), types: (tf.string, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.float64, tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32)>`

I have 25 columns and `tf.contrib.data.SqlDataset()` creates 25 different `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor`. How can I bring them together? Therefore, I can use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`?

Comment: So just to confirm, you've already migrated entire dataset from _PostgreSQL_ to _SQLite3_, right? If not, you may like to [go through this](https://jjude.com/pg-to-sqlite/), as you've already noticed SQLite is a better companion with TF.

Comment: Yes I did. My problem is how to manipule SqlDataset on Tensorflow using tf.data API

Answer (score 1):

You use the methods on [SqlDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/SqlDataset) to manipulate the data. For example, create a train/test split with:

```
test_dataset = dataset.take(1000) 
train_dataset = dataset.skip(1000)
```

I would get rid of unneeded columns in the `SELECT` statement to reduce the size of the data as early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

That import step doesn't look right.  Can you try it like this?

```
import pypyodbc 
cnxn = pypyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                        "Server=ServerName;"
                        "Database=TestDB;"
                        "Trusted_Connection=yes;")

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Actions')

for row in cursor:
    print('row = %r' % (row,))
```

Comment: yes I could use external library which I did in the end using psycopg2 but I wanted to use Tensorflow's its own function and manipulate there using tf.data API.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but for anyone reading this in the future: SQLAlchemy is a great way to handle any SQL interfaces. Just create a model class that matches your DB schema, then use the query API to get your data.

If you have very large datasets, you can use use `yield_per` or `slice` to easily retrieve it in chunks, as de

Answer (score 0):

here is a link for the [driver-installation](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#ubuntu18) on possible linux distros.
and another [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-odbc-to-connect-any-database-directly-to-jupyter-notebook-19741b4b748) with installation und connection examples.
my code looks like as following,

```
import pandas as pd # data processing
import pyodbc
pyodbc.drivers()

server = 'MY_SERVER' 
database = 'MY_DB' 
username = 'DB_USER' 
password = 'DB_PASS'  
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                  'SERVER='+server+
                  ';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

query = 'SELECT * FROM XXX'
sales = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)
print(sales.head(26))
print(sales.info())
```